# Verify if the user already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a login in python flask, and when registering a new user I would like to search in the database.  If the user is already registered, the code should send a message that the user already exists.

**This is my registration code:**

```
@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("register.html")
    else:
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        code = request.form['code']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
        hash_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, email, code, password) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name,email,code,hash_password,))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        session['name'] = request.form['name']
        session['email'] = request.form['email']
        session['code'] = request.form['code']
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Before using the `INSERT INTO` SQL query, you could check if the user exists with a `SELECT FROM` SQL query.

```
cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name=%s AND email=%s AND code=%s", (name,email,code))
```

If one of the fields (name, email or code) is a primary key, then you do not even need to check the other values and make the query simpler be only using the primary key field, e.g.

```
cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE code=%s", (code,))
```

Nevertheless, if the response contains a row, the user exists, if it does not contain any rows, the user does not exist.

```py
if cur.rowcount == 1:
  return redirect(url_for('user_already_exists')) # Send a response redirecting to a page saying the user already exists, if you have a page for that
```

If you are asking about how to write SQL queries (which it seems), then I suggest you read SQL tutorials first, for example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

Comment: Google these keywords: `python flask custom response` if you want to just send a message without redirecting.